# Vector performance suffering

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I've been working on state space exploration and was originally using a map to store the assignment of the world states like `map<Variable *, int>`, where variables are objects in the world with a domain from 0 to n where n is finite. The implementation was extremely quick for performance, but I noticed that it does not scale well with the size of the state space. I changed the states to use `vector<int>` instead, where I use the id of a variable to find its index in the vector. Memory usage improved greatly, but the efficiency of the solver has tanked (gone from <30 seconds to 400+). The only code that I modified was generating the states and validating if the state is the goal. I can't figure out why using a vector has degraded performance, especially since the vector operations should only take linear time at worst.

Originally this is was how I generated nodes:

```
State * SuccessorGen::generate_successor(const Operator &op, map<Variable *, int> &var_assignment){

    map<Variable *, int> values;
    values.insert(var_assignment.begin(), var_assignment.end());
    vector<Operator::Effect> effect = op.get_effect();
    vector<Operator::Effect>::const_iterator eff_it = effect.begin();

    for (; eff_it != effect.end(); eff_it++){
        values[eff_it->var] = eff_it->after;
    }
    return new State(values);
}
```

And in my new implementation:

```
State* SuccessorGen::generate_successor(const Operator &op, const vector<int> &assignment){

    vector<int> child;
    child = assignment;

    vector<Operator::Effect> effect = op.get_effect();
    vector<Operator::Effect>::const_iterator eff_it = effect.begin();

    for (; eff_it != effect.end(); eff_it++){
        Variable *v = eff_it->var;
        int id = v->get_id();
        child[id] = eff_it->after;
    }
    return new State(child);
}
```

(The goal checking is similar, just looping over the goal assignment instead of operator effects.)

Are these vector operations really that much slower than using a map? Is there an equally efficient STL container I can use that has a lower overhead? The number of variables is relatively small (<50) and the vector never needs to be resized or modified after the for loop.

Edit:

I tried timing one loop through all the operators to see timing comparisons, with the effect list and assignment the vector version runs one loop in 0.3 seconds, while the map version is a little over 0.4 seconds. When I comment that section out the map was about the same, yet the vector jumped up to closer to 0.5 seconds. I added `child.reserve(assignment.size())` but that did not make any change.

Edit 2:

From user63710's answer, I've also been digging through the rest of the code and noticed something really strange going on in the heuristic calculation. The vector version works fine, but for the map I use this line `Node *n = new Node(i, transition.value, label_cost); open_list.push(n);`, but once the loop finishes filling the queue the node gets totally screwed up. Nodes are a simple struct as:

```
struct Node{
    // Source Value, Destination Value
    int from;
    int to;
    int distance;
    Node(int &f, int &t, int &d) : from(f), to(t), distance(d){}
};
```

Instead of having `from, to, distance`, it replaces `from` and `to` with `id` with some random number, and that search does not do what it should and is returning much faster then it should. When I tweak the map version to convert the map to a vector and run this:

`Node n(i, transition.value, label_cost); open_list.push(n);` 
the performance is about equal to that of the vector. So that fixes my main issue, but this leaves me wondering why using `Node *n` gets this behaviour opposed to `Node n()`?

Comment: Have you also tried unordered_map? And was your vector sorted? You can do things faster if you make sure the vector is sorted at all times.

Comment: Do you have any other information about what's causing the slowdown? There's always compiling with `g++ -pg` and using `gprof`. Otherwise, I'm assuming `get_id()` isn't computationally expensive, are the ids generated by `eff_it->var->get_id()` sequential or random?

Comment: I don't want the vector sorted as the index of the value corresponds to a specific variable, ie var0 is at index 0 etc. ID's are generated when the input is parsed, so when var0 is loaded the Variable has a private int and that is what gets returned.

Comment: Do var_assignment and assignment have the same number of elements? Are there any unused `id` in your `assignment` vector?

Comment: Yes both have the same number of elements, and the `assignment` vector is sized to the number of elements and never changes. The vector/map is the same size for all states.

Comment: I'd try commenting out the actual application of the effects in both versions and running it again, just to see if its some sort of allocation/copy slowdown.

Comment: @mn22 Try changing `vector<int> child;` to `static vector<int> child;`. I'm curious if it will help (doubt it but maybe). Make sure to keep the assignment on a separate line.

Comment: Is your code generated for optimized/release build ? And I don't understand your time evolution as initially you speak of 30 -> 400+ and your measurements now show only an increase of 25%

Comment: profile it before optimization

Comment: @user63710 I tried that, no change. I also ran it using gprof and the calls for `generate_successor()` all show 0.00, same with calls to the State constructor.

Comment: @mn22 Well it was worth a try with static. Is the 0.00 for `self` or is it for `children`? Can you tell what's taking up most of the time? I feel like your problem might be elsewhere if there are only ~50 elements and each call takes on the order of 0.1-0.4s.

Comment: According to the profile on a 13 second run over 12.2 are spent doing heuristic calculations (this is expected, and the heuristic implementation hasn't changed), and the only time the vector is accessed is to see if the value at index `i` equals the goal value for variable `i`. I don't see how this would cause the bottleneck if my map implementation makes the identical calls to the heuristic as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you say, the sizes of these structures are fairly small (~50 elements), I have to think that the issue is somewhere else. At least, I don't think it involves the memory accesses or allocation of the vector/map.

Some example code I made to test: Map version:

```
unique_ptr<map<int, int>> make_successor_map(const vector<int> &ids,
    const map<int, int> &input)
{
    auto new_map = make_unique<map<int, int>>(input.begin(), input.end());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i)
        swap((*new_map)[ids[i]], (*new_map)[i]);

    return new_map;
}

int main()
{
    auto a_map = make_unique<map<int, int>>();

    // ids to access
    vector<int> ids;

    const int n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        a_map->insert({i, rand()});
        ids.push_back(i);
    }

    random_shuffle(ids.begin(), ids.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i)
    {
        auto temp_map = make_successor_map(ids, *a_map);
        swap(temp_map, a_map);
    }

    cout << a_map->begin()->second << endl;
}
```

Vector version:

```
unique_ptr<vector<int>> make_successor_vec(const vector<int> &ids,
    const vector<int> &input)
{
    auto new_vec = make_unique<vector<int>>(input);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ids.size(); ++i)
        swap((*new_vec)[ids[i]], (*new_vec)[i]);

    return new_vec;
}

int main()
{
    auto a_vec = make_unique<vector<int>>();

    // ids to access
    vector<int> ids;

    const int n = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        a_vec->push_back(rand());
        ids.push_back(i);
    }

    random_shuffle(ids.begin(), ids.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i)
    {
        auto temp_vec = make_successor_vec(ids, *a_vec);
        swap(temp_vec, a_vec);
    }

    cout << *a_vec->begin() << endl;
}
```

The map version takes around 15 seconds to run on my old Core 2 Duo T9600, and the vector version takes 0.406 seconds. Both we're compiled on G++ 4.9.2 with `g++ -O3 --std=c++1y`. So if your code takes 0.4s per iteration (note that it took my example code 0.4s for 1 million calls), then I'm really thinking your problem is somewhere else.

That's not to say you aren't having performance decreases due to switching from map->vector, but that the code you posted doesn't show much reason for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create vectors without reserving space. Vectors store elements contiguously.  That ensures constant access to elements.

So everytime you add an item to the vector (for example via your inserter), the vector has to reallocate more space and eventuelly move all the existing elements to a reallocated memory location.  This causes slowdown and considerable heap fragmentation.

The solution to this is to [`reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) elements if you know in advance how many elements you'll have.  Or if you don't reserve() larger chunks and compare `size()` and [`capacity()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/) to check if it's time to reserve more.

Comment: I don't see how this would be any different from the map example though? Also I only see one copy assignment, and then some more assignments, no insertion.

Comment: I think there is no guarantee of contiguousity on maps.  This means taht if you add a new element, the element gets allocated somewhere and the map refers to it.    You can check by printing out the addresses of the elements in the two cases.

Comment: Yeah, but in the end the same amount of memory needs to be allocated (more in the case of the map due to the keys/structure, assuming there are no empty spots in the vector). So I would expect it to be worse for the map if anything.

Comment: One other thing, I never insert into the vector. There is one copy made when `child = assignment`, and everything in the loop is just accessing an index within the vector. So if the vector has 10 elements the largest id is 9 and there is no changing that size during the programs lifetime.

Comment: @user63710 No, because in the map, you just allocate memory for one element, whereas for vectors you have to allocate memory the for ALL the elements (new one + all the others) AND move all the elements to the new place (invoking move or copy constructor).  If you have a couple of million elements as in my benchmark two weeks ago, it really makes a difference, moving GB of memory back and forth.